# Reindex monthly indices into daily indices in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, reindex

I have some monthly indices like `monthly-2021-01`, `monthly-2021-02` containing documents with a date field.

I would like to break those monthly indices into daily ones

so that documents from the 1st of January in `monthly-2021-01` are then stored in `daily-2021-01-1`.

I tried with the [_reindex](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) API but found no way of adding a condition for the reindexed documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be done with

```
{
        "source": {
            "index": "index-src",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": {
                        "range": {"date": {"gte": "start-date", "lt": "end-date"}},
                    }
                }
            },
        },
        "dest": {
            "index": "index-dest"
        }
    }
```

Then do this for each mont/date relation

Comment: Be cautious with `gt/lt` as you might miss some documents. Prefer the use of `gte/lt` instead.